# Symfony2 Json parse with dates

Tags: php, json, symfony

Have this JSON:

Online viewable at:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=97bbcb19871e89ff0702f8547589a688

Trying to parse it out, but some fields names are dates, so I am not sure how to do it.

I want to parse  and store in DB (persist in MongoDB):

- date
- reference (neo_reference_id)
- name
- speed (kilometers_per_hour)
- is hazardous (is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid)

Trying to do it like this, so I can get reference, name, speed and is hazardous:

```
  $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

  foreach($data['near_earth_objects'] as $neos)
  {
    foreach($neos as $item)
    {
      $output->write($item['name']);
    }
  }
```

How to get the date field correspondingly?

What is the best practice to parse JSON data in Symfony2?

Thanks,

**Update 1:**

Tried as Half Crazed has answered:

```
$jd = new JsonDecode();
$neo_obj = $jd->decode($response->getBody(),"json");
foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as $date => $object) {
  // store $date here
  $output->write($date);
  foreach($date as $objects) {
  $links = $objects['links'];
  $neo_ref_id = $objects['neo_reference_id'];
  $output->write($links);
  $output->write($neo_ref_id);
  }
}
```

$date is there, but in the second look it make a warning and nothing gets displayed.

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Any tips?

Thanks,

**Update 2:**

This does it.

Can it be improved for better performance and code readability :) ?

```
        $jd = new JsonDecode();
        $neo_obj = $jd->decode($response->getBody(),"json");
        foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as $date => $object) {
          $output->writeln("date:".$date);
          foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as $object1) {
            foreach($object1 as $object2)
            {
              $output->writeln("name:".$object2->name);

              $output->writeln("neo_reference_id:".$object2->neo_reference_id);
              $output->writeln("is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid:".$object2->is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid);
              foreach($object2->close_approach_data as $object3)
              {
                $i=0;
                foreach($object3->relative_velocity as $object4)
                {
                  if($i===1)
                  {
                    $output->writeln("speed:".$object4);
                  }
                  $i=$i+1;
                }
              }


            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/JsonDecode.html) for decoding (check if it's decodable, then decode)

The best way to store these, in my opinion, is to iterate over `$obj->near_earth_objects`. For (a rough) example:

```
foreach($obj->near_earth_objects as $date => $object) {
  // store $date here
  foreach($date as $objects) {
    $links = $objects['links'];
    $neo_ref_id = $objects['neo_reference_id'];
    // etc..

    // store in db
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Half Crazed !!! I updated the question with Update 1 based on your suggestion. Unfortunately, there is a problem with the second loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. Can you see my Update 2 and maybe suggest improvements ?

Comment: @android_dev you don't need to do `foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as [...]) {` twice. You can remove that inner `foreach` and still loop over `$object` instead. `$object` will be everything in the `near_earth_objects[date]` array. You should feel free to `var_dump($var)` anytime you're unsure if you should access an array item or object property, eg `$array['key']` versus `$obj->prop`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to see if that works:

```
foreach($neos as $item){
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($item); $i++){
        $output->write( $item['$i'] );
    }
}
```

Not certain, but I think it might work. This gets each sub-element in the Date element, which is what you want correct? If not, update your post.